# React on UniqueKeyViolation in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, unique-constraint

I have 2 Tables in SQLAlchemy (using `declerative_base()`) that are joined via a seperate Table relationship

```
# no comment on the wired naming....
site_word = Table('word_site', Base.metadata,
    Column('site_id', Integer, ForeignKey('sites.site_id'), nullable = False, primary_key = True),
    Column('word_id', Integer, ForeignKey('site_words.word_id'), nullable = False, primary_key = True))
```

Word mapping

```
class Word(Base):
   # snip
   word =  Column('word', Text, nullable = False, unique = True)
   sites = relationship('Site', secondary = site_word, back_populates = 'words')
```

Site mapping

```
class Site(Base):
   # snip
   words = relationship('Word', secondary = site_word, back_populates = 'sites')
```

Inserting works like expected, inserting of already existing words fails of course due to `unique` in `Word.word`.

I tried using a [before_insert](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/orm/events.html?highlight=before_insert#sqlalchemy.orm.events.MapperEvents.before_insert) event to check if the item already exists.

```
event.listen(Word, 'before_insert', some_event)
```

I can get the information to identify the word uniquly as expected but I don't know how to add a new value to the join table (`site_word`).

I could write a trigger or procedure for the database but don't want to move too much logic into the database (don't know if this would be possible since the `Site` wouldn't be known at that time). I could remove the constraint for the `word`-column but I still can't figure out how to access the information (the other end of the join) to create an entry in the join table, but not in the `Word` table.

I am looking for a way to create a entry in the `site_word` and `Site` table **only**.

*update 1:*
I could attach the event to the `Site` but I don't see a possibility to get the information of the to-be-inserted Site. Is there a possibility to save the Site and create the join-relation afterwards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to do it. Mark Gemmill's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7092396/react-on-uniquekeyviolation-in-sqlalchemy/7097214#7097214) got me thinking in the right direction.

I need to listen to an [AttributeEvent](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/orm/events.html#sqlalchemy.orm.events.AttributeEvents.append) instead of an MapperEvent.

```
event.listen(Site.words, 'append', test_event, retval = True)
```

Then I can do something like:

```
def test_event(target, value, initiator):
    try:
        return session.query(Word).filter(Word.word == value.word.lower()).one()
    except sqlalchemy.orm.exc.NoResultFound:
        return value
```

This either returns the existing word from the table or simply returns the mapped object that needs to be persisted.

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult to see the problem without an example of how you are working with your objects. I take it you are trying to do something like this:

```
site = Site()
site.words.append(Word('Someword'))
session.add(site)
session.commit()
```

This will of course raise an `IntegrityError` if 'someword' already exists. To get around this, you need to first query the database for the word before adding it to the site:

```
def get_unique_word(session, word):
    try:
        return session.query(Word).filter(Word.word==word).one()
    except sqlalchemy.orm.exc.NoResultFound:
        return Word(word)

site = Site()
site.words.append(get_unique_word(session, 'someword'))
session.add(site)
session.commit()
```

If this is completely off base, then you'll have to describe your problem in greater detail.

Comment: Your suggestion isn't the answer but got me into the right direction of solving it. Thanks for your effort. Don't know why I was ignoring the other events from the API ;)